# SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 180-day Trial - Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, tde

I just installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise trial version on a Windows 2003 Server, and tried to implement Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) on my database. It failed with error:

> Transparent Data Encryption is not available in the edition of this SQL Server

Here's what I did and the results:

```
USE master;
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'some_password';

--Result: Completed successfully

CREATE CERTIFICATE MyCert WITH SUBJECT = 'My Certificate';

--Result: Completed successfully

USE mydatabase;
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE MyCert

--Result: Msg 33117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Transparent Data Encryption is not available in the edition of this SQL Server instance.
```

Does Microsoft restrict using TDE on their trial versions?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  Turns out that I didn't uninstall the Express version properly before installing the Enterprise trial version, so the server was still running in Express mode.  I did a complete server overhaul, reinstalled the Enterprise trial from scratch, and got TDE to work.